# How to extract sub strings of size 3 that starts with consonant in a string using regex in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

My regex is giving only one sub string. How it should be modified to get all possible sub strings.Regex i wrote is

```
print re.findall(r'([^aeiou]\w{2})+', 'banana')
```

o/p: `['ban']`

Expected O/p: `['ban', 'nan']`

Comment: See https://ideone.com/VZjbFx

Comment: that works! thank you!